# get idToken with firebase auth emulator with postman

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I can access the idToken with postman on this address

`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key={{apiKey}}`

```
{
  "email": "email@test.com",
  "password": "12345678",
  "returnSecureToken": true
}
```

I want to access the idToken firebase auth emulator. I could not find the correct endpoint on emulator.

How can take idToken on auth emulator?

Answer (score 3):

The REST endpoints for the auth emulator are at `localhost:$PORT/$API/$ENDPOINT`, so for example  `localhost:1234/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp`.

If you're having trouble accessing the endpoint at this location, please edit your question to show what you tried.